Solving a system of quadratic vector-matrix equations
I have a system of $n$ equations of the following form
$$0=a_i^TX^TD_iXa_i$$
were $a_i\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, $X\in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)\times n}$, and $D_i\in\mathbb{R}^{(n+1)\times(n+1)}$ which is diagonal. I would like to solve for $X$. I have a few questions

Does there exist an $X$ that solves this, and is it unique? Does making $X$ a square matrix help with existence/uniqueness?
If a solution does exist, how can I find it? Either by analytical methods or efficient numerical methods?
What type of problem is this? i.e. is this a quadratic matrix equation since it is quadratic in $X$, is this a quadratic vector equation since the $a_i$ are vectors, or is it some other form of problem altogether?

Edit
The matrix $A=[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric, positive semidefinite.
